# why SIGHUP signal not received when becoming an Orphaned Process Group

Tags: c, linux, process, jobs

In the manual for GNU libc about [orphaned process groups](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Orphaned-Process-Groups.html), it mentioned :

```
“process groups that continue running even after the session leader 
has terminated are marked as orphaned process groups. 

When a process group becomes an orphan, its processes are sent a SIGHUP 
signal. Ordinarily, this causes the processes to terminate. However, 
if a program ignores this signal or establishes a handler for it 
(see Signal Handling), it can continue running as  in the orphan process
 group even after its controlling process terminates; but it still 
cannot access the terminal any more. ”
```

I write a test program, but when the process group becomes an orphan, its process didn't receive the SIGHUP signal. I am wondering why?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


static void  
sig_hup(int signo) //**never get called ???**
{
    printf("SIGHUP received, pid = %ld\n", (long)getpid());
}

static void
pr_ids(char *name)
{
    printf("%s: pid = %ld, ppid = %ld, pgrp = %ld, tpgrp = %ld\n",
        name, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)getpgrp(),
        (long)tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO));
    fflush(stdout);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char    c;
    pid_t   pid;

    pr_ids("parent");
    pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {       // parent 
        sleep(5);
        exit(0);         // parent exit;
    } else {
        pr_ids("child");
        setsid();        //create new session, and "child" becomes the session leader
        pid = fork();
        if(pid>0) {
            sleep(20);
            exit(0);     // "child" exit
                         // so the process group become an orphan process group
        }
        else{
            pr_ids("grandson");
            signal(SIGHUP, sig_hup);    // establish signal handler 
            sleep(60);                  // now becoming orphan process group
            printf("end\n");
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That document section is talking specifically about the loss of a controlling terminal of a process that had one—usually by a modem hangup, or the virtual equivalent (ending an ssh session, etc).  (I think the phrasing in the document could be improved here).  When you use `setsid()` here, you give up access to the controlling terminal by the time `setsid()` returns, so there is no controlling terminal to lose from there forward.

You could `open()` a tty device (such as a pty slave) to gain a controlling terminal (note that you may have to do some additional operation as well—FreeBSD requires a `TIOCSCTTY` ioctl), then lose it again, and *then* you should get the `SIGHUP` signal.

Answer (score 3):

Orphaned process groups get `SIGHUP` followed by `SIGCONT` if they're stopped when they become orphaned.

Sleep is not enough, you need:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP); //or raise(SIGSTOP);
```

In addition to that, POSIX doesn't require that `SIGHUP` and `SIGCONT` be sent if the orphaning was caused by `setsid()` or `setprgrp()` because then it wasn't caused by an exiting process innocently unaware of job control (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html ).

However, with `kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)` instead of that `sleep(60)` in the child, you will get a stopped orphan with your program even if you don't call `setsid()`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void  
sig_hup(int signo) //**never get called ???**
{
    printf("SIGHUP received, pid = %ld\n", (long)getpid());
}

static void
pr_ids(char *name)
{
    printf("%s: pid = %ld, ppid = %ld, pgrp = %ld, tpgrp = %ld\n",
        name, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)getpgrp(),
        (long)tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO));
    fflush(stdout);
}

int
main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;

    pr_ids("parent");
    pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {       // parent 
        sleep(5);
        _exit(0);         // parent exit;
    } else {
        pr_ids("child");

        /*setsid();        //create new session, and "child" becomes the session leader*/

        pid = fork();
        if(pid>0) {
            sleep(2);
            exit(0);     // "child" exit
                         // so the process group become an orphan process group
        }
        else{
            pr_ids("grandson");
            signal(SIGHUP, sig_hup);    // establish signal handler 
            kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
            printf("end\n");
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

should get you a `SIGHUP` in the child after the parent dies (5s).