# Daemon sighup use

Tags: linux, session, signals, fork, daemon

Let us assume I create a daemon by double forking

[Daemonization and SIGHUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103871/daemonization-and-sighup)

According to the above question the second child does not receive a sighup when the session leader(the first child exits). Then why do we need to ignore sighup?